# Postfix is forwarding/relaying spam

Tags: postfix, spam-prevention, forwarding, amavis

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 machine with Postfix 3.1.0 and virtual mailboxes (iredmail).

I'm using postscreen (with a local Bind server), Amavis with ClamAV and SpamAssassin.

The amount of received spam is pretty low. The problem is, that the server seems to forward emails which are actual calssified as spam.

For example I have a mailbox on my server `foo@mydomain.com`. This mailbox has a forwarding to `bar@otherdomain.com` (the emails are kept in the mailbox). Spam filtereing works pretty well for the messages delivered to `foo@mydomain.com` on my server. In contrast the mailbox `bar@otherdomain.com` gets the messages plus all the spam.

I'm using Amavis with *smtpd_proxy_filter*, hence emails are only accepted if they are not considered spam, all other emails are rejected.

```
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd -o smtpd_proxy_filter=127.0.0.1:10024 -o content_filter=
```

My guess is to append the smptd_porxy_filter to the relay service in /etc/postfix/master.cf

```
relay      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp -o smtpd_proxy_filter=127.0.0.1:10024 -o content_filter=
```

I didn't find anything usefull about this topic. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Can you explain/reword that part: "For example there are no spam emails in the mailbox on my server, but in the mailbox of the forwarding receipient."

Comment: Sure, I updated my post.

Comment: Is "otherdomain.com" is in `@local_domains_maps ` in Amavis configuration ? I doubt this is the root of the problem since, at this time, `To:` is supposed to remain the original address, not the alias...

Comment: I have `@local_domains_maps = 1;`

I'm not sure, but seems to be fine: https://forum.iredmail.org/topic3800-iredmail-support-localdomainsmaps-in-amavisdnew.html

(I'm using mysql to store virtual mailbox users)